# sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -i test.sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `test.sql` script file that I'm trying to install but after running this line of code i have this issue:

```
sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -i test.sql
```

Issue:

> Named Pipes Provider: No process is on the other end of the pipe.
>
> Communication link failure

How can I run my SQL script that created database with all the tables?

Comment: Did you start the localdb process? `sqllocaldb start` from a cmd line?

Comment: LocalDB instance "mssqllocaldb" started. But i have the same issue